# premake5: add files to "Copy Bundle Resources" build phase

Tags: xcode, premake

I have some image files I need to add to an Xcode project. I need the files to be included in the `Copy Bundle Resources` build phase. I also need `Type` to be set to `Data` to avoid any compression or processing by Xcode.

Is this possible with premake5?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter to select the files and then do an embed action

```
filter "files:%{prj.name}/Res/**"
            buildaction "Embed"
```

This example adds all of the files in the Res folder to the Copy Bundle Resources. Although XCode won't show them in the Copy Bundle Resources list they should still show up in the target directory after you build and run the project.

https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/buildaction